# Am I correct with my thinking for these expressions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If  $y(r,\theta) = r\sin(\theta) \implies dy = \sin(\theta)dr + r\cos(\theta)d\theta$

(1) What if  $y(r) = r\sin(\theta)$? Would that $\implies dy = \sin(\theta) dr \iff \frac{dy}{dr} =\sin(\theta)$?

(2) Does my first line $\implies \frac{dy}{dr} = \sin(\theta) + r\cos(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dr}$ ?

If so, is it correct to state that $\frac{dy}{dr}$ is different from (1)'s $\frac{dy}{dx}$ because in (1) it's a single variable function and in (2) it's a multivariable function, even though both the functions are exactly the same expressions?

(3) Lastly, can I replace the $dy, dr$ and $ d\theta$ with $\partial y, \partial r$ and $\partial \theta$ in the expression in my first line?

Answer (score 1):

$$y(r,\theta) = r\sin(\theta) \implies dy = \sin(\theta)dr + r\cos(\theta)d\theta$$it represents the total derivative. 
But this does not implies$$\frac{dy}{dr} = \sin(\theta) + r\cos(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dr}$$

**Note:** $\frac{dy}{dx}~$ does not mean $~dy~$ divided by $~dx~$. The expression $~\frac{dy}{dx}~$ represents the rate of change of the dependent variable (or expression),$~ y~$, with respect to the (independent) variable $~x~$.

Also here $~\frac{d\theta}{dr}~$ has no meaning at all. Both $~r~$ and $~\theta~$ are independent variable and hence $~\frac{d\theta}{dr}=0~$

You have to write is as follows $$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}y(r,\theta)=\sin \theta $$and $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}y(r,\theta)=r\cos \theta $$

and then by the definition of total derivative $$dy=\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}~dr+\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}~d\theta$$
$$\implies dy = \sin(\theta)dr + r\cos(\theta)d\theta$$

But if $$y(r) = r\sin(\theta)$$then $$\frac{d}{dr}y(r)=\sin \theta$$because in this case $~\sin \theta~$ is a constant or, you can tell that $~y~$ is independent of $~\theta~$ .

Comment: So why can't we go from $dy = \sin(\theta)dr + r\cos(\theta)d\theta$ 
  to   $\frac{dy}{dr} = \sin(\theta) + r\cos(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dr}$?